# What are the key semantic differences between Ruby and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby, programming-languages, v8, spidermonkey

If one were to implement Ruby on top of a Javascript engine (either in the browser or on top of standalone V8 or Spidermonkey), what would be the key impedance mismatches between the Ruby and JS object models ?

Comment: This question occurred to me while looking at the architecture of the SpiderMonkey tracing JIT - whether it could also serve as the guts of a Ruby implementation. It would also be nice to write Ruby for the browser (like GWT does for Java) - in that case I imagine that there would be many restrictions on the libraries and language features that could be used.

Comment: I think that the biggest problem pointed out so far (by Marc-André Lafortune in a comment) is the missing method/const and autoload functionality. A future version of Ecmascript will contain "proxies" that would probably allow efficient implementation: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure proxies are in whatever the TraceMonkey version in Firefox 4 is, and I expect other implementors to follow suit, since they are *immensely* useful for security. (See, e.g. Mark S. Miller's *SES* (Secure ECMAScript) and *Dr. SES* (Distributed Resilient Secure ECMAScript) work).

Comment: The TraceMonkey tracing JIT consists mostly of `nanojit`, which is a language-independent JIT compiler anyway, doesn't it? If all you want is a Ruby implementation with a tracing JIT, there is really no need to compile to ECMAScript, just hook up `nanojit` to Rubinius. Or write a Ruby implementation in PyPy, whose tracing JIT is freakishly awesome. (Incidentally, PyPy has an ECMAScript backend, so you actually kill two birds with one stone. More like 4 birds, since a Ruby implementation written in PyPy would be able to run on natively, on the JVM, on .NET and on ECMAScript.)

Comment: @Jörg thanks for the pointer to PyPy - that does look like an interesting project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most in-your-face one is obviously the fact that ECMAScript is prototype-based and Ruby is class-plus-mixin-based. Also, in Ruby, encapsulation is done with objects, in ECMAScript with closures.

However, my guess is that Ruby's control flow constructs are going to be a much bigger hurdle than its object model. After all, [James Coglan's JS.Class](http://JSClass.JCoglan.Com/) *is* basically an implementation of Ruby's object model in ECMAScript and it's not that big.

ECMAScript simply lacks the tools needed to build your own control-flow constructs on top of it. Typically, you need either `GOTO`, continuations or proper tail calls. If you have one of those, you can easily implement everything else: exceptions, loops, switches, threads, `Fiber`s, generators, coroutines, … you name it.

But ECMAScript doesn't have them (and for good reason, at least in the case of `GOTO`). The only control-flow construct ECMAScript has that is powerful enough to be able to build other constructs on top of is exceptions. Unfortunately, those are pretty slow. (Nonetheless, they *have* been used as an implementation substrate, for example in the Microsoft Live Labs Volta compiler, which used ECMAScript exceptions to implement .NET exceptions, iterators, generators and even threads.)

So, basically you are stuck with implementing at least your own call stack if not an entire interpreter (as is the case with HotRuby), performing global CPS transforms or something like that.

Basically, what you *want* from a Ruby engine running on top of ECMAScript, is

1. a faithful implementation of the RubySpec (specifically the control-flow constructs such as threads, fibers, `throw`/`catch`, exceptions etc.),
2. performance and
3. tight integration with ECMAScript (i.e. the ability to pass objects and call methods back and forth between the two languages).

Unfortunately, when you have to resort to tricks like managing your own stack, doing CPS transforms, building on top of exceptions, … it turns out that you can only pick two of the three goals.

Comment: What's with all the goto hate?

Comment: @dsimcha: You have some very curious definition of "hate".

Comment: You would probably need to do some copying of methods from object to object to simulate mixins. Thanks for the heads-up on generators etc - I will think about how those can be simulated without exceptions.

Comment: I don't think that the differences between object-based and closure-based encapsulation is that great. There are many tricks in the JS world for implementing private methods and properties that would seem applicable.

Answer (score 3):

1. Ruby has block-level scoping of local variables, JavaScript has function-level scoping
2. Ruby's inheritance + mixins would likely be problematic to implement simply using JavaScript's prototypal inheritance
3. Ruby's arity checking for method/lambda invocation and is more strict than JavaScript's permissive passing
4. Ruby has true, enforced constants; JavaScript may not (depending on which version the interpreter is using)
5. Class variables (ugh) have no equivalent in JaveScript, and so will require special handling
6. Ruby's has green threads in the core, JavaScript does not

Comment: Good list. I would definitely add that compatibility for hooks like `method_missing`, `const_missing` & `autoload` also imply that every single method call or constant lookup has to be wrapped (say like `myobject._call_method_("foo", ..)`

Comment: The pattern function(){..}() (i.e. immediately calling an inline anon function) is not unknown in the JS world - that would allow simulation of block scopes.

Comment: Adding a mixin to a JS object would require copying the methods from the mixin to the object, which has a cost - is there anything more to it than that ?

Comment: I know that JRuby uses native OS threads rather than green - does that cause a problem ? In the browser, threading would not be much of a requirement, or would require explicit use of Web Workers, so that may not be a large issue.

Comment: @Marc-André - the "missing" handlers do sound like the biggest problem. They would require a null-check of every reference before calling or using, which would be costly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @NickMain Regarding the implementation of a Mixin by copying methods, this would not necessarily reflect the 'live' nature of Mixins (reopening a mixin and adding a method after mixing it in).

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is Turing-complete, so theoretically you can implement anything, including other programming languages in it. **It doesn't matter how different the implementation (JavaScript) and the target language (Ruby) are**. The *impedance mismatch* between languages like Ruby and C is huge, and there you have Ruby, Python, Perl, and JavaScript itself, all implemented in C.

Implementing Ruby in JavaScript should be orders of magnitude easier than doing so in a lower level language. To your advantage, you have that much of Ruby and Ruby's standard library are written in Ruby itself, so once you get a basic interpreter going, things should gradually be more and more downhill.

Implementing an *efficient* Ruby interpreter in JavaScript may be harder, but it's still possible. You may end up translating Ruby to JavaScript so the excellent optimizers available can kick in.

So, do not think about the differences between Ruby and JavaScript. Take a look at the standard implementation of Ruby, and think about how you would implement ***that*** in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I am thinking more about how to cross-compile from an existing Ruby implementation to Javascript rather than implementing a full Ruby interpreter/REPL in the browser.

Comment: @Nick Cross-compilation will require most of the work an interpreter would, so approach it the same way. Take a look at the runtime support in the implementation of Ruby in C and/or Java, and think about how you would implement that in JavaScript. Not translating the code, but rather figuring out the data structures and functionality needed to support Ruby at runtime.